# SkiaSharp ArcTo Method does not draw curve

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, skia, skiasharp

I am trying to draw an arc on a SkiaSharp canvas view using following code.

```
path3.ArcTo(new SKPoint(0, h/2), 1.57f, SKPathArcSize.Large,
            SKPathDirection.Clockwise, new SKPoint(w/2, h));
```

But instead of a curve, it is drawing a straight line. How to make it as a curve?

**Complete Code**

```
 private void OnPainting(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
 {

     var surface = e.Surface;
     var canvas = surface.Canvas;
     canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);

        var w = e.Info.Width;
        var h = e.Info.Height;

        var pathStroke3 = new SKPaint
        {
            IsAntialias = true,
            Style = SKPaintStyle.StrokeAndFill,
            Color = new SKColor(240, 0, 100, 250),
            StrokeWidth = 5
        };

        var path3 = new SKPath { FillType = SKPathFillType.EvenOdd };
        path3.MoveTo(0, h/2);
        path3.ArcTo(new SKPoint(0, h/2), 1.57f, SKPathArcSize.Large, SKPathDirection.Clockwise, new SKPoint(w/2, h));
        path3.LineTo(0, h);
        path3.Close();
        canvas.DrawPath(path3, pathStroke3);


 }
```

XAML

```
 <Grid x:Name="controlGrid" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="White" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="6*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <views:SKCanvasView PaintSurface="OnPainting" EnableTouchEvents="True" 
     Touch="OnTouch" HeightRequest="300" Grid.Row="0"/>
 </Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `x` radius is zero, thus `ArcTo` adds a line to the path from the current point to the exit point.

> arcTo appends Line to xy if either radii are zero, or if last Path Point equals (x, y). arcTo scales radii r to fit last Path Point and xy if both are greater than zero but too small.

You can do something like:

```
path3.ArcTo(new SKPoint(100, 100), 0, SKPathArcSize.Large, SKPathDirection.Clockwise, new SKPoint(w / 2, h));
```

[image]

But I do not know what your drawing intent is; concave, convex, bounded, unbounded, etc... but some other examples using `ConicTo` that might be closer to what I think your intent might be:

```
path3.ConicTo(w / 3, h / 2, w / 2, h, 0.50f);
```

[image]

```
path3.ConicTo(0, h - (h / 5), w / 2, h, 0.50f);
```

[image]

You might want to look at the official docs to understand how `ArcTo` resolves into arcs, conics and moves:

- https://skia.org/user/api/bmh_SkPath?cl=9919#arcTo

Answer (score 1):

I am using `ConicTo` for the following as per the reply from @SushiHangover

References:

1. [Three Types of Bézier Curves - developer.xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/skiasharp/curves/beziers/)
2. [Three Ways to Draw an Arc - developer.xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/skiasharp/curves/arcs/)
3. [Experimental SkPath - skia.org](https://skia.org/user/api/bmh_SkPath?cl=9919#arcTo)

[image]

**Code**

```
private void OnPainting(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{

     var surface = e.Surface;
     var canvas = surface.Canvas;
     canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);

        var w = e.Info.Width;
        var h = e.Info.Height;
        var h12 = h - (h / 8);
        var h8 = h - (h / 6);
        var h4 = h - (h / 3);


        var pathStroke3 = new SKPaint
        {
            IsAntialias = true,
            Style = SKPaintStyle.StrokeAndFill,
            Color = new SKColor(240, 0, 100, 250),
            StrokeWidth = 5
        };

        var path3 = new SKPath { FillType = SKPathFillType.EvenOdd };
        path3.MoveTo(0, h4);
        path3.ConicTo(0, h8, w/2, h12, 0.50f);
        path3.LineTo(w/2, h);
        path3.LineTo(0, h);
        path3.Close();
        canvas.DrawPath(path3, pathStroke3);

        var pathStroke6 = new SKPaint
        {
            IsAntialias = true,
            Style = SKPaintStyle.StrokeAndFill,
            Color = new SKColor(100,0, 240,  250),
            StrokeWidth = 5
        };
        var path6 = new SKPath { FillType = SKPathFillType.EvenOdd };
        path6.MoveTo(w, h4);
        path6.ConicTo(w, h8, w / 2, h12, 0.50f);
        path6.LineTo(w / 2, h);
        path6.LineTo(w, h);
        path6.Close();
        canvas.DrawPath(path6, pathStroke6);


        var pathStroke4 = new SKPaint
        {
            IsAntialias = true,
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
            Color = new SKColor(0, 0, 255),
            StrokeWidth = 5
        };

        var path4 = new SKPath { FillType = SKPathFillType.EvenOdd };
        path4.MoveTo(0, h4);
        path4.LineTo(w / 2, h4);
        canvas.DrawPath(path4, pathStroke4);


        var pathStroke5 = new SKPaint
        {
            IsAntialias = true,
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
            Color = new SKColor(0, 255, 0),
            StrokeWidth = 5
        };
        var path5 = new SKPath { FillType = SKPathFillType.EvenOdd };
        path5.MoveTo(0, h8);
        path5.LineTo(w / 2, h8);
        canvas.DrawPath(path5, pathStroke5);

        var path7 = new SKPath { FillType = SKPathFillType.EvenOdd };
        path5.MoveTo(w/4, h8);
        path5.LineTo(w /4, h);
        canvas.DrawPath(path5, pathStroke5);

  }
```